# Modelpop up unload on when Click on any button on Panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i have a modelpopup extender in my page.i am using this to search some data from database like customer etc. when i put search criteria on panel and as i click on serach the model popup goes and i want been able to make it visible as soon i finish the searching a code and then i select that code.

kindly help me out

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your cancelbutton property ??